# Как в Django добавить несколько фотографий в одну модель?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-model

Видел этот вопрос на  форуме ранее, но решение не помогло. Хочу добавить несколько фотографий к товару, как это можно сделать почти во всех интернет-магазинах

```
 image = models.ImageField(blank = True) 
 image1 = models.ImageField(blank = True)
 image2 = models.ImageField(blank = True)
 image3 = models.ImageField(blank = True)
```

Но я хочу сделать по-нормальному.
Я искал разные решения в интернете, но пока ничего не выходит. Хочется, чтобы при добавлении товара (пока что через стандартную админ панель, потом добавлю форму) можно было загрузить значения всех моих панелей (уже есть) и столько фотографий, сколько хочет пользователь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если проблема в том, чтобы не задавать конкретное количество столбцов для фотографий, то Вам нужно создать отдельную таблицу для фоток и установить связь один-ко-многим между товарами и фотографиями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь создать ещё одну модель с полями: товар и фото.
Поле товар связываешь с моделью товара.
И можешь добавлять не ограниченное кол-во фото для товара.

`class Photo(models.Model): product = models.ForeignKey('имя модели продукта', on_delete=models.CASCADE) image = models.ImageField(blank = True)`

Comment: Спасибо, а как в шаблоне вывести все фотографии? ```Photo.image....``` А дальше что?

Comment: И почему-то я могу добавить только одну фотографию к одному товару